# Executing stored procedure gets error "access violation or syntax error"

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am new to VBA (macros) and have some requirement to run the stored procedures from VBA. Hence, I have written my first simple stored procedure, but that throws an error while executing via VBA code, while it does work fine when executed in SQL Server. I'm doing some silly mistake which I'm unable to find. I have great hope you guys can find it in one go.

Stored procedure:

```sql
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
USE test
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO  

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployeeData] 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployeeData]
    @empid INT = NULL -- parameter that can supply value as per requirement
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM employee 
    WHERE empid > ISNULL(@empid, empid)
Go
```

VBA code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Exec_StoredProc_Click()

 Dim con As ADODB.Connection
 Set con = New ADODB.Connection
 Dim res As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim mobjCmd As ADODB.Command
 Set mobjCmd = New ADODB.Command
 Dim strConn As String
 'Dim strQuery As String
 'con.Close

 strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
 con.Open strConn



With mobjCmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = "Exec [dbo].[spEmployeeData]"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@empid", adInteger, adParamInput, 32767, 102)
    ' repeat as many times as you have parameters

    .Execute
End With

'Debug.Print spEmployeeData

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error message says "access violation"? An access violation has nothing to do with authorization (the more likely error message), it's a very serious bug involving reading or writing to memory your process isn't allowed (by the OS) to read/write from/to... which I strongly doubt can happen with a mere syntax error.

Comment: `WHERE empid > ISNULL(@empid, empid)` is not a good predicate. Instead, consider just ensuring that the `@empid` parameter is non-`NULL`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The error message could be a string in the existing program inside a catch-all `On Error...` statement. This is why I dislike VBA :D

Comment: Upon which line do you get the error?

Comment: Why do you have `32767` in the `CreateParameter` call? The 4th parameter is `Size`, but `adInteger` doesn't need a `Size` value. You should omit the parameter as it's optional by using a black space: `.CreateParameter("@empid", adInteger, adParamInput, , 102)`.

Comment: @Dai and how is VBA to blame for this? I can make you a catch-all scope that pops a similarly misleading error in C# too. Or in PHP - wait no, I don't do PHP.. point is, the error is much more likely to come straight out of ADODB (relayed verbatim from the SQL connection) than to be a made up "access violation" error. There *are* legit reasons to dislike VBA, but that isn't one of them.

Comment: "My employer's legal department requires me to declare that every opinion I express on Stack Overflow is also the opinion of the entire company, of every employee, and of the executive management. I am never wrong and am always right."  ...nevermind  (basically what I meant was "bad code is on the coder, not the language ;-)

Comment: @JNevill my money is on the `.Execute` statement :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Correct, however VBA's design predates the "pit of success" philosophy that modern languages like Go and Rust are embracing, consequently VBA makes it easy to do the wrong thing - for new and "non-professional" VBA people it's much easier just to do something like `On Error GoTo ShowMsgBox` than actual structured error handling. Languages like Rust and Go instead make the compiler force the user into handling errors correctly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Err... what is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170107/discussion-between-mathieu-guindon-and-dai).

Comment: I have tried as per all your suggestion but still its not working while stored proc is perfectly fine with SQL server as executing and producing the right results. Could you please help me here to resolve it else I won't be able to move ahead?

Comment: Even with simple stored proc contains only "select * from employee" it does not work while stored proc is working fine in SQL server. I'm not able to figure out the issue.This error comes in when "mobjCmd.Execute" triggers. Please assist me to resolve the issue.

Comment: This issue has been resolved by changing cmdCommandType to 1

Comment: Closing as a duplicate because the reason is exactly the same. `"Exec [dbo].[spEmployeeData]"` with `adCmdStoredProc` gives exactly that error. Changing `cmdCommandType` to 1 is not the correct fix.